# Troubleshooting ML.NET machine learning model issues

Tags: c#, machine-learning, data-cleaning, ml.net

I am trying to learn how ML.Net works. I have no experience with machine learning before, so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I have tried to setup a model for candlestick data from stock exchanges. I have loaded the data from the exchange into an enumerable of a class with properties for timestamp, open, high, low, close and volume. (ohlcv are all decimals and timestamp is a DateTime)

When I try to load the list into an IDataView using Context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable

I get the following error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not determine an IDataView type for member High (Parameter 'rawType')
```

I have checked the data and there are no 0 values and its not nullable so I am not sure what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Also, will these feature columns need to be encoded? if so what is the best type of encoding for double values and dates?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the decimal type is not supported. It must be converted to a none nullable float. Also call features need to be the same datatype for the model to be trained with the pipeline

Comment: Wow. Decimal is still not supported in Microsoft.ML 1.7.1 (latest as of 2022-07-07). At least with the default schema auto-detection.